# Is there an alternative way to have smooth scroll instead of using webkit-overflow-scroll touch?

Tags: css, ipad, scroll, smooth-scrolling

does anybody know how to have a nice smooth scrolling in a div element instead of using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch? I need it for my iPad. When I touch the iPad to "scroll down", it has to be smoothly.

The problem is that in my application -webkit is bugging. I just want to have the inner div element to scroll smoothly. Anybody any solutions?

```
<div id="mainContainer">
 <div id="innerContainer">
   <div class="box">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    ...
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go throgh the below link in that you can get custom scolling plugin use that, i think it will help you
http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

Comment: actually I don't want to use a big library for just a div to have a smooth scrolling. it takes too much performance because my project is huge and it would be really waste. isnt there a different way?